# Get the percentage in a data range

Tags: mysql, sql, percentage

I'm new to SQL and I'm trying to solve this query. I have 3 tables:

-Question
-Answer
-Student

A student can make answers to a question, then an answer has the atribute of the chosen answer, and the table question as an atribute of the right answer to that question.

An answer has a date.

I need to know, in a specific date, the percentage of correct answered dates.

I made this querys:

**Get all the answers made, by date, by a specifica student:**

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM answer an where an.StudentID = 'X1'
GROUP BY an.AnswerDate
```

**Get the correct answers, by date, by a specific student:**

```
SELECTCOUNT(*)     
FROM answer an1, question q1
where an1.questionID = q1.IDquestion
and an1.ChosenAnswer = q1.Answer
and an1.StudentID = 'X1'
GROUP BY an1.AnswerDate
```

Now I can't figure out how can I join them, and get the percentage...

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Learn modern JOIN syntax, i.e. "FROM answer an1 JOIN question q1 ON an1.questionID = q1.IDquestion
and an1.ChosenAnswer = q1.Answer". Much easier, especially when OUTER JOINS are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
SELECT SUM(     

CASE   WHEN an1.ChosenAnswer = 1.Answer 
               THEN 1 
               ELSE 0 
       END) as Correct
 ,     COUNT(an1.ChosenAnswer) as Answers
 ,     SUM(     

CASE   WHEN an1.ChosenAnswer = 1.Answer 
               THEN 1 
               ELSE 0 
       END) / COUNT(an1.ChosenAnswer) * 100 as Percentage

FROM answer an1, question q1
where an1.questionID = q1.IDquestion
and an1.ChosenAnswer = q1.Answer
and an1.StudentID = 'X1'
GROUP BY an1.AnswerDate
```